# Add two keyframe movements to css

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

Trying to create two different types of keyframe movements with CSS.  What's the easiest and cleanest way to accomplish this?  I want the clouds to move up like they currently do but I also would like them to shake a little bit as they are going up. Thanks for your help.

```
#clouds div {position:absolute; width:230px;}
#clouds div img{ display:block; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
.Blittle img{ width:42px; float:left;}
.BlittleUP img{ width:51px; float:right}
.Bmedium img{ width:90px; float:left}
.BmediumUP img{ width:120px; float:right}
.BmediumUPUP img{ width:140px}
.Bbig img{ width:280px; float:right}

.Blittle { animation: moveclouds 14s infinite linear forwards;-webkit-animation: moveclouds 14s infinite linear forwards;-moz-animation: moveclouds 14s infinite linear forwards;-o-animation: moveclouds 14s infinite linear forwards;}
.BlittleUP  { animation: moveclouds 16s infinite linear forwards; -webkit-animation: moveclouds 16s infinite linear forwards;-moz-animation: moveclouds 16s infinite linear forwards;-o-animation: moveclouds 16s infinite linear forwards;}
.Bmedium   { animation: moveclouds 17s infinite linear forwards;-webkit-animation: moveclouds 17s infinite linear forwards;-moz-animation: moveclouds 17s infinite linear forwards;-o-animation: moveclouds 17s infinite linear forwards;}
.BmediumUP  { animation: moveclouds 18s infinite linear forwards;-webkit-animation: moveclouds 18s infinite linear forwards;-moz-animation: moveclouds 18s infinite linear forwards;-o-animation: moveclouds 18s infinite linear forwards;}
.BmediumUPUP  { animation: moveclouds 19s infinite linear forwards;-webkit-animation: moveclouds 19s infinite linear forwards;-moz-animation: moveclouds 19s infinite linear forwards;-o-animation: moveclouds 19s infinite linear forwards;}
.Bbig  { animation: moveclouds 22s infinite linear forwards;-webkit-animation: moveclouds 22s infinite linear forwards;-moz-animation: moveclouds 22s infinite linear forwards;-o-animation: moveclouds 22s infinite linear forwards;}


.BC-1 {left:5%; }
.BC-2 {left:14.5%;}
.BC-3 {left:25%;}
.BC-4 {left:37.5%; }
.BC-5 {left:50%;}
.BC-6 {left:62.5%; }
.BC-7 {left:75%;}
.BC-8 {left:87.5%; }


.BC-1 img{ margin-top:500px}
.BC-2 img{margin-top:100px}
.BC-3 img{ margin-top:300px}
.BC-4 img{ margin-top:150px}
.BC-5 img{margin-top:350px}
.BC-6 img{ margin-top:0px}
.BC-7 img{ margin-top:700px}
.BC-8 img{ margin-top:100px}
.Blittle.BC-8 img{margin-top:350px}
.BlittleUP.BC-3 img{margin-top:0px}
.BmediumUP.BC-4 img{margin-top:700px}



@keyframes moveclouds { 
    0% {  transform: translate(0px, 700px);}
    100% { transform: translate(0px, -1200px);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveclouds { 
    0% {  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 700px);}
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -1200px);}
}

@-moz-keyframes moveclouds { 
    0% {  -moz-transform: translate(0px, 700px);}
    100% { -moz-transform: translate(0px, -1200px);}
}
@-o-keyframes moveclouds { 
    0% {  -o-transform: translate(0px, 700px);}
    100% { -o-transform: translate(0px, -1200px);}
}
#clouds .container { position:absolute; top:50%;     -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);   -moz-transform: translate(0%, -50%);   -ms-transform: translate(0%, -50%);   -o-transform: translate(0%, -50%);   transform: translate(0%, -50%);     width: 100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you double wrap the clouds in HTML? Have parent wrapper use the existing 'moveclouds' keyframes and the child wrapper use a new animation that 'shakes' them.

Comment: Didn't work...     
.shake:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}



keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

Comment: @JeffroJeffro what is your current HTML? I am suggesting to keep everything the same but add another DIV inside (a child) with a different class calling different animations. If you would start a fiddle I could help edit to show you.

Comment: @JeffroJeffro Thanks! What I was suggesting is adding animation to the insides. So in the updated fiddle I added an animation call to "#clouds div img" just so you can both happening together, but clearly you'd want your own animation settings (maybe different for each parent class):https://jsfiddle.net/3x2zfe5p/